# How to use jQuery/Ajax to perform MySQL Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery to check if the username that the user entered in a form is already taken. Below are the relevant codesnippets in Java, and existence.php.

```
*javascript*
var username = document.register.username.value;
usernameTaken = checkUserExistence(username, 'username');

function checkUserExistence(str, type){
    var dataString = '?str=' + str + '&type=' + type;
    if($.trim(str).length>0 && $.trim(type).length>0){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "existence.php",
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#submit").val('Sending...');},
            success: function(data){
                if(data){
                    $("#submit").val('Succes!');
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    $("#submit").val('Failure!');
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
*/JavaScript*

<?php

include("inc/connect.php");

$data = $_POST["str"];
$type = $_POST["type"];

switch($type){
    case "username":
        $resultUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$data' ") or die(mysql_error());
        if( mysql_num_rows($resultUsers) == 1 ){
            echo 1;
        }
        break;
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?
My website is supposed to show live hints to the users, like 'your username is too short' etc. All hints are working, but the ones where it should say 'your username is already taken' won't show. The form gets processed to my PHP-register function, where usernames that are already taken get rejected, so somehow the checkUserExistence-function and the existence.php page are not working.

*Edit:*

For a live demonstration of my code, go to:
http://beta.somentus.nl/index.php
The usernames 'Admin', 'Somentus' and 'Rik' are already taken, try them out :)

Comment: Be careful with your `if(data){` test for success, because if an error response includes a non-empty string your JS will see it as success. Better to test for a specific value. (Also, Java != JavaScript.)

Comment: I have no idea how to use that part, I copied it from another website where it seemed to work. What should I check for?

Comment: I beg your pardon, I edited the mistake :)

Comment: In PHP print out the $_POST array and see what it contains. That should help you know what key(s) to use when you want to print stuff from the data that is posted

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
```

should be:

```
$data = $_POST["str"];
```